# Using Python to count morphemes in a file & list them in columns

Tags: python, count

This is the script that has very kindly been given to me as a starter:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import with_statement    # needed for Python 2.5
from itertools import chain

def chunk(s):
    """Split a string on whitespace or hyphens"""
    return chain(*(c.split("-") for c in s.split()))

def process(latin, gloss, trans):
    chunks = zip(chunk(latin), chunk(gloss))
    # now you have to DO SOMETHING with the chunks!

def main():
    with open("examples.txt") as inf:
        try:
            while True:
                latin = inf.next().strip()
                gloss = inf.next().strip()
                trans = inf.next().strip()
                process(latin, gloss, trans)
                inf.next()    # skip blank line
        except StopIteration:
            # reached end of file
            pass

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing anything, but the output is simply blank, taking me back to $.

I'm trying to do the following:
I have a text with a language other than English, broken up into morphemes (parts of each word) using hyphens, with the English gloss (linguistic translation of each morpheme) and a direct translation below.

eg.

> Itali-am fat-o profug-us Lavini-a-que ven-it
>
> Italy-Fem:Sg:Acc fate-Neut:Sg:Abl fleeing-Masc:Sg:Nom Lavinian-Neut:Pl:Acc come:Perf-3-Sg:Indic:Act
>
> 'in flight [driven] by fate came to Italy and the Lavinian [shores]'

I'll have several texts such as the above in one file - i.e.

> blank line
>
> a line of latin broken up with hyphens
>
> a line of gloss broken up with corresponding hyphens, using colons to join elements
>
> a line of translation
>
> blank line
>
> latin
>
> gloss
>
> translation
>
> ad infinitum.

What I need to do is write a file that gives me the following output:

```
Itali:    1    Italy
am:    1    Fem:Sg:Acc
fat:    1    fate
o:    1    Neut:Sg:Abl
profug:   1    fleeing
us:    1    Masc:Sg:Nom
Lavini:    1    Lavinian
a:    1    Neug:Pl:Acc
que:    1    come:Perf
ven:    1   3
it:     1   Sg:Indic:Act
```

where the first column represents the first line of text without hyphens; the second column indicates the number of occurrences (it's only 1 each in this example), and the third column is the English translation of the first column, as written in the text.

If there's a latin morpheme with no corresponding English gloss/translation, the Latin column will be as normal but the English column will print [unknown], like:

```
a:  1   [unknown]
```

And if the opposite, i.e. an English morpheme with no corresponding Latin, it should print

```
[unknown]:  1   kitten
```

Finally, the prog needs to be able to deal with homophonous morphemes (i.e. two identically spelled latin morphemes with different meanings).
e.g.

```
a:  16  Neuter:Plural
a:  28  Feminine:Singular
```

Again, it's homework, and any pointers would be wonderful. Working on putting together some script now to upload here for critique!

Comment: It'd be helpful if you posted what you have so far.  Otherwise it'll be hard to help

Comment: In `process`, you end up with `chunks` as a list of original-translation tuples. You then have to **do** something with that list, ie keep a count of how many times you see each original-translation pairing.

Comment: Your program runs, but you don't see anything because you don't ask it to print out anything. Make `process()` print out and/or return `chunks`. If you're not sure what `chunks` looks like, examine it from the interactive prompt.

Comment: sorry for the late comment, I went to bed! >.< I'm very new to all this, thanks so much for being patient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processing the file is a bit tricky because of the multiline structure; rather than the usual line-by-line iteration, I suggest something like this (I presume the file does not actually begin with a blank line, per your example, but that it uses blank lines as separators):

```
with open("input.txt") as inf:
    try:
        while True:
            latin = inf.next().strip()
            gloss = inf.next().strip()
            trans = inf.next().strip()
            process(latin, gloss, trans)
            inf.next()    # skip blank line
    except StopIteration:
        # reached end of file
        pass
```

`process` must then split `latin` and `gloss` into chunks and pair them appropriately:

```
from itertools import chain

def chunk(s):
    """Split a string on whitespace or hyphens"""
    return chain(*(c.split("-") for c in s.split()))

def process(latin, gloss, trans):
    chunks = zip(chunk(latin), chunk(gloss))
```

Calling this like

```
process(
    "Itali-am fat-o profug-us Lavini-a-que ven-it",
    "Italy-Fem:Sg:Acc fate-Neut:Sg:Abl fleeing-Masc:Sg:Nom Lavinian-Neut:Pl:Acc come:Perf-3-Sg:Indic:Act",
    "in flight [driven] by fate came to Italy and the Lavinian [shores]")
```

leaves `chunks` containing

```
[('Itali', 'Italy'),
 ('am', 'Fem:Sg:Acc'),
 ('fat', 'fate'),
 ('o', 'Neut:Sg:Abl'),
 ('profug', 'fleeing'),
 ('us', 'Masc:Sg:Nom'),
 ('Lavini', 'Lavinian'),
 ('a', 'Neut:Pl:Acc'),
 ('que', 'come:Perf'),
 ('ven', '3'),
 ('it', 'Sg:Indic:Act')]
```

The rest is an exercise for the student - keeping a running count of the chunks, then sorting and displaying it appropriately. Hope that helps!

Comment: hmm, I'm getting a strange syntax error, as soon as I enter the following: >>> with open("examples.txt") as inf:
<stdin>:1: Warning: 'with' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    with open("examples.txt") as inf:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax . 
Doesn't like it either way, if I do python ./examples.txt (with #!usr/bin/python as first line), or if I type it directly. Wah :(

Comment: @user1374310: Are you, by chance, using Python 2.5? It does not support the `with` keyword; you will have to revert to `inf = open("input.txt"); do stuff; inf.close()` (or switch to a more up-to-date Python!).

Comment: @user1374310: actually, after a bit more reading: you should be able to prepend `from __future__ import with_statement` and it should work. You **still** should be using a more up-to-date Python ;-)

Comment: - I left this for a few hours, just got back to it. Soooooo confused! (see edit to op). Thanks for your help, though!